# Syntax for Masking Polygons which do not contain line using cross-layer filtering in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs, cql-filter

I have two vector layers in GeoServer.

1. One is a polygon like;
   [image]

and another one is a polyline like;
[image]

By cross-layer filtering, I want to select `only those polygons` from `1st layer` which are crossed by any `specifically chosen polyline` from `2nd layer`.

I have used the [CQL_Filter](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html) as per [the documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html#filter-ecql-reference) as;

```
INCLUDE;WITHIN(geometry, collectGeometries(queryCollection('railway_shapefile', 'geometry', 'FROM=''DELHI'' AND TO=''AMBALA''')))
```

where `FROM` & `TO` are the attributes from polyline shapefile

```
http://localhost:8585/geoserver/aasdagrometgis/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&LAYERS=aasdagrometgis:INDIA_DIST_717_GCS,aasdagrometgis:railway_shapefile&CQL_FILTER=INCLUDE;WITHIN(geometry,%20collectGeometries(queryCollection(%27railway_shapefile%27,%20%27geometry%27,%20%27FROM=%27%27DELHI%27%27%20AND%20TO=%27%27AMBALA%27%27%27)))&bbox=68.18624877929688%2C6.755565643310547%2C97.41529846191406%2C37.07667922973633&width=740&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A4326&styles=&format=application/openlayers
```

[image]

**Basically, what is want is that `if a select a single line running between two stations`, then `only the polygons from/through which line is crossing` should be `selected/filtered/highlighted`. The rest should be `masked/not selected/not highlighted`.**

and The layer does not open if I delete `INCLUDE` from the CQL_FILTER

```
CQL_FILTER=WITHIN(geometry, collectGeometries(queryCollection('railway_shapefile', 'geometry', 'FROM=''DELHI'' AND TO=''AMBALA''')))
```

What would be the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query fails when you leave out the `INCLUDE` because with 2 layers you must have 2 filters. But you don't want the first one to be `INCLUDE` because that will draw all of your polygons. You want that one to be the cross layer query filter and the **second** one to select just the rail line you want. So I would expect something like this to work:

```
CQL_FILTER=WITHIN(geometry, collectGeometries(queryCollection('railway_shapefile', 'geometry', 'FROM=''DELHI'' AND TO=''AMBALA''')));FROM='DELHI' AND TO='AMBALA'
```

Comment: i tried this way ```http://localhost:8585/geoserver/aasdagrometgis/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&LAYERS=aasdagrometgis:INDIA_DIST_717_GCS,aasdagrometgis:railway_shapefile&%20CQL_FILTER=CQL_FILTER=WITHIN(geometry,%20collectGeometries(queryCollection(%27railway_shapefile%27,%20%27geometry%27,%20%27FROM=%27%27DELHI%27%27%20AND%20TO=%27%27AMBALA%27%27%27)));FROM=%27DELHI%27%20AND%20TO=%27AMBALA%27&bbox=68.18624877929688%2C6.755565643310547%2C97.41529846191406%2C37.07667922973633&width=740&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A4326&styles=&format=application/openlayers``` but it did not worked.

Comment: It returned all the polygons from 1st layer and all the lines from second layer; Earlier I was getting all the polygons from 1st layer but only the selected line from second layer. @IanTurton

Comment: you have two `CQL_FILTER`s in that URL

Comment: It worked well with ```CROSSES(geometry, collectGeometries(queryCollection('railway_shapefile', 'geometry', 'FROM=''DELHI'' AND TO=''SAHARANPUR''')));FROM='DELHI' AND TO='SAHARANPUR'``` Thanks a ton with the syntax.

Comment: Final URL was something like ```http://localhost:8585/geoserver/aasdagrometgis/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&LAYERS=aasdagrometgis:INDIA_DIST_717_GCS,aasdagrometgis:railway_shapefile&CQL_FILTER=CROSSES(geometry,%20collectGeometries(queryCollection(%27railway_shapefile%27,%20%27geometry%27,%20%27FROM=%27%27DELHI%27%27%20AND%20TO=%27%27AMBALA%27%27%27)));FROM=%27DELHI%27%20AND%20TO=%27AMBALA%27&bbox=68.18624877929688%2C6.755565643310547%2C97.41529846191406%2C37.07667922973633&width=740&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A4326&styles=&format=application/openlayers```